# Scala - mapping a list of integers to a method that receives java.lang.Object

Tags: scala

Working in Scala-IDE, I have a Java library, in which one of the methods receives `java.lang.Object`. And I want to map a list of `Int` values to it. The only solution that works is:

```
val listOfInts = groupOfObjects.map(_.getNeededInt)

for(int <- listOfInts) libraryObject.libraryMethod(int)
```

while the following one:

```
groupOfObjects.map(_.getNeededInt).map(libraryMethod(_)
```

and even

```
val listOfInts = groupOfObjects.map(_.getNeededInt)

val result = listOfInts.map(libraryObject.libraryMethod(_))
```

say

> type mismatch; found : Int required: java.lang.Object Note: an
>   implicit exists from scala.Int => java.lang.Integer, but methods
>   inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous. This is to   avoid a
>   blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Int to any AnyRef. You
>   may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Integer`.

and something like

```
val result = listOfInts.map(libraryObject.libraryMethod(x => x.toInt))
```

or

```
val result = listOfInts.map(libraryObject.libraryMethod(_.toInt))
```

does not work also.

1) Why is it happening? As far as I know, the `for` and `map` routines do not differ that much!

2) Also: what means `You may wish to use a type ascription: x: java.lang.Integer`? How would I do that? I tried designating the type explicitly, like `x: Int => x.toInt`, but that is too erroneus. So what is the "type ascription"?

**UPDATE:**

The solution proposed by T.Grottker, adds to it. The error that I am getting with it is this:

> - missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$3) => x$3.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Object])
> - missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$3) => x$3.asInstanceOf{#null#}[java.lang.Object]{#null#})   {#null#}

and I'm like, OMG, it just grows! Who can explain what all these `<null>` things mean here? I just want to know the truth. (NOTE: I had to replace <> brakets with # because the SO engine cut out the whole thing then, so use your imagination to replace them back).

Comment: Did you try an explicit cast in groupOfObjects.map(_.getNeededInt).map(libraryMethod( _.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Object])?

Comment: `listOfInts.map(x => libraryObject.libraryMethod(x.toInt))` should work

Comment: Just a guess. Could this be because your try to call the java method with the primitve type `int` and not an object? In java land you can't do autounboxing and "widening" at the same time, not sure if the same applies to Scala thou.

Comment: @elbowich nope, does not work. Did you try it?

Comment: @Grottker nope, it takes us deeper into the mystery, see the update. Does it work in your environment?

Comment: @Emil I have just tried in Java this: `void test(Object obj){}` and then `test(3);` - it works. Not sure that I understand what you're talking about.

Comment: @noncom You are correct. My bad. What I was thinking about was that you can not call the method `public void foo(Long l)` with a `int`. This is since `Integer` (which the `int` can be autoboxed to) can not be widened to `Long`. It does however work if `foo` takes an `Object` (since Integer obviously is an Object). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @noncom That wasn't exactly about `Int/Object` mismatch, but rather about passing a function to `libraryMethod` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type mismatch tells you exactly the problem: you can convert to `java.lang.Integer` but *not* to `java.lang.Object`.  So tell it you want to ask for an `Integer` somewhere along the way.  For example:

```
groupOfObjects.map(_.getNeededInt: java.lang.Integer).map(libraryObject.libraryMethod(_))
```

(The notation `value: Type`--when used outside of the declaration of a `val` or `var` or parameter method--means to view `value` as that type, if possible; `value` either needs to be a subclass of `Type`, or there needs to be an implicit conversion that can convert `value` into something of the appropriate type.)

Comment: Ok, very good, thanks! This is a really handy concept. How could that be that I have missed it! Now you have widened my understanding. What about widening it some more by answering on the 1st question?

Comment: Does the `for` construct use this or a similar view conversion internally?

Comment: @noncom - I don't know why it works with the for loop; maybe type inference realizes it's got to be a subclass of `Object`?